# connect two matrixes by columns and extract sub matrix

Tags: r, perl, matrix, subset

I have two matrixes (e.g., A and B). I would like to extract columns of B based on the order of A's first column:

For example

matrix A

```
name score
a 0.1
b 0.2
c 0.1
d 0.6
```

matrix B

```
a    d   b   c   g   h
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.2
0.2 0.1 0.4 0.7 0.1 0.1
...
```

I want matrix B to look like this at the end

matrix B_modified

```
a    b   c   d
0.1 0.3 0.4 0.2
0.2 0.4 0.7 0.1
```

Can this be done either in perl or R? thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Something like this? `b[, a[, "name"]]`

Comment: Hi @Arun, thanks that is great. I am getting some output but it is not exactly in the order i want it to be. I was checking the output of the a[, "name"], and it lists the names and add '13500 levels: a b...z'. Can this be the reason that is not sorting the names properly?

Comment: Yes, just do: `a[, "name"] <- as.character(a[, "name"])` before to do the step mentioned before.

Comment: @Arun I just realized i forgot to mention something. The matrix B has more columns. A is a subgroup of the main matrix. I think i have to select those first and then sort them. Can i get a sub of matrix B? just selecting those columns that are in A? The same command should work though I think. But i still get the following error message: Error in `[.data.frame`(b, , a[, "name"]) : 
  undefined columns selected

Comment: @Arun Can I extract the columns of B that only exist in A?

Comment: The fact you are seeing levels is telling us your objects are data.frames, not matrices. The "undefined columns selected" error is saying that `A$name` contains values that are not column names of `B`, do `setdiff(A$name, colnames(B))` to see which ones. Tell us or what you want to do with these.

Comment: @Arun: Why did you remove the Perl tag?

Comment: Thanks for noticing. The word "perl" in the question eluded me while reading.

Answer (score 2):

I've no idea what problems you're facing. Here's how I've done it.

```
## get data as matrix
a <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="name score
a 0.1
b 0.2
c 0.1
d 0.6", stringsAsFactors=FALSE) # load directly as characters

b <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="a    d   b   c   g   h
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.6 0.2
0.2 0.1 0.4 0.7 0.1 0.1", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

a <- as.matrix(a)
b <- as.matrix(b)
```

---

Now subset to get your final result:

```
b[, a[, "name"]]
#        a   b   c   d
# [1,] 0.1 0.3 0.4 0.2
# [2,] 0.2 0.4 0.7 0.1
```

Comment: @user1007742, You seem confused to pick an answer :)

Comment: They both worked fine for me and I thought I can choose the two as the answer but the system does only let me choose one :) so I left it as it is

Comment: The point of choosing having "one" answer is to choose the one that *you* find best answers the question. It's nice for the community for the questions to remain answered. I'd advise you to choose one of them that you find best answers. No one's going to chase you :).

Answer (score 2):

The error :

```
[.data.frame(b, , a[, "name"]) : undefined columns selected
```

means that you try to get a column non defined in `b` but exist in `a$name`. One solution is to use `intersect` with `colnames(b)`. This will convert also the factor to a string and you get the right order.

```
b[, intersect(a[, "name"],colnames(b))] ## the order is important here
```

For example , I test this with this data:

```
b <- read.table(text='
a    d   b   c
0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4
0.2 0.1 0.4 0.7',header=TRUE)

a <- read.table(text='name score
a 0.1
z 0.5
c 0.1
d 0.6',header=TRUE)

b[, intersect(a[, "name"],colnames(b))]


    a   c   d
1 0.1 0.4 0.2
2 0.2 0.7 0.1
```

Answer (score 2):

If your data originates as an R data structure then it would be perverse to export it and solve this problem using Perl. However, if you have text files that look like the data you have shown, then here is a Perl solution for you.

I have split the output on spaces. That can be changed very simply if necessary.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

sub read_file {
  my ($name) = @_;
  open my $fh, '<', $name;
  my @data = map [ split ], <$fh>;
  \@data;
}

my $matrix_a = read_file('MatrixA.txt');
my @fields = map $matrix_a->[$_][0], 1 .. $#$matrix_a;

my $matrix_b = read_file('MatrixB.txt');
my @headers = @{$matrix_b->[0]};
my @indices = map {
  my $label = $_;
  grep $headers[$_] eq $label, 0..$#headers
} @fields;

for my $row (0 .. $#$matrix_b) {
  print join('  ', map $matrix_b->[$row][$_], @indices), "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
a  b  c  d
0.1  0.3  0.4  0.2
0.2  0.4  0.7  0.1
```